# How to optimized multiple for loops to make code more readable

Tags: java, json, api, loops, refactoring

I've written a method to read json and generate data based on different combination.
For example lets say I've 3 json parameter and i wanna pass different permutation of json data.
So combination would be :
1 - F,T,T
2 - T,F,T
3 - T,T,F
4 - T,T,T

I used negativeCaseList to get false data and postitiveCaseList to get true data.
My task is to optimize this code to make it more readable.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < negativeCaseList.size(); i++) {
   if (!negativeCaseList.get(i).isEmpty()) {
      ArrayList<?> negativeDataAsList = (ArrayList<?>) negativeCaseList.get(i);
      for (int j = 0; j < negativeDataAsList.size(); j++) {
         ParameterData negativeParameterData = (ParameterData) negativeDataAsList.get(j);

         for (int k = 0; k < postitiveCaseList.size(); k++) {
            ArrayList<?> positiveDataAsList = (ArrayList<?>) postitiveCaseList.get(k);
            for (int l = 0; l < positiveDataAsList.size(); l++) {
               ParameterData positiveParameterData = (ParameterData) positiveDataAsList.get(l);
               if (Utility.validateString(negativeParameterData.getParameterName())) {
                  if (!negativeParameterData.getParameterName().equals(positiveParameterData.getParameterName())) {

                     if (!positiveParameterData.parameterType.startsWith("System")) {
                        dictionary.put(positiveParameterData.getParameterName(), positiveParameterData.getValue());
                     } else {

                        dictionary.put(positiveParameterData.getParameterName(), positiveParameterData.getValue());
                     }

                     paramName = positiveParameterData.getParameterName() + "," + paramName;
                     if (Utility.hasHTMLTags(positiveParameterData.getValue().toString())) {
                        paramValue = ("<xmp style='padding:0px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap'>" + positiveParameterData.getValue().toString() + "</xmp>") + "," + paramValue;
                     } else {
                        paramValue = positiveParameterData.getValue() + "," + paramValue;
                     }
                  } else {
                     dictionary.put(negativeParameterData.getParameterName(), negativeParameterData.getValue());
                     paramName = negativeParameterData.getParameterName() + "," + paramName;
                     if (Utility.hasHTMLTags(negativeParameterData.getValue().toString())) {
                        paramValue = ("<xmp style='padding:0px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap'>" + negativeParameterData.getValue().toString() + "</xmp>") + "," + paramValue;
                     } else {
                        paramValue = negativeParameterData.getValue() + "," + paramValue;
                     }
                  }
               } else {
                  listofParameter = negativeParameterData.getValue();
                  if (Utility.hasHTMLTags(negativeParameterData.getValue().toString())) {
                     paramValue = ("<xmp style='padding:0px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap'>" + negativeParameterData.getValue().toString() + "</xmp>") + "," + paramValue;
                  } else {
                     paramValue = negativeParameterData.getValue() + "," + paramValue;
                  }
               }

            }
         }

         //json ="";
         if (!dictionary.isEmpty()) {
            json = ParameterTransform.ObjectToString(dictionary);
         } else {
            json = ParameterTransform.ObjectToString(listofParameter);
         }
         preData.putAll(Utils.fillTestDetailsInPreData(requestRule));

         if (requestRule.getiRegistrationNo()) {
            JSONObject stringToJson = new JSONObject(json);
            json = securityObject.buildMainJson("10401", "f41f9ac6-1090-4851-bc7a-4a2355dd10c4",
                  stringToJson);
         }
         jsons.add(json);
         app_logs.info("Json " + jsons);
         //reportData.add(json+"|"+paramName+"|"+paramValue);
         if (Utility.hasHTMLTags(json)) {
            reportData.add("<xmp style='padding:0px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap'>" + json + "</xmp>");
         } else {
            reportData.add(json);
         }
         pName.add(paramName.toString());
         pValue.add(paramValue.toString());
         app_logs.info("data " + reportData);
         //app_logs.info("pName : " + pName.toString());
         //app_logs.info("pValue : " + pValue.toString());
         paramName = "";
         paramValue = "";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In general: Use functions instead of putting everything in all at once. There also seems to be a bug in your code: if(!positiveParameterData.parameterType.startsWith("System")) has the same execution in both true and false case.

Comment: Try breaking this up into individual methods/functions (maybe even separate classes).  That should help with legibility, maintainability, and ease of testing if you are unit testing your code.

Comment: @JoschJava actually that if condition supposed to handle user defined data types. But I'm still working on it.

Comment: I've replaced all loops with stream API to decrease number of lines.